# ORMLite createOrUpdate() records while preserving specific column?

Tags: java, android, sql, database, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite to manage database tables which contain lists of lookup values for a data collection application. These lookup values are periodically updated from a remote server. However, I'd like to be able to preserve the data in a specific column while creating or updating the records, since I would like to store usage counts (specific to the device) associated with each lookup value. Here's how I'm updating the records:

```
        //build list of new records
        final List<BaseLookup> rows = new ArrayList<BaseLookup>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonRows.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonRow = jsonRows.getJSONObject(i);

            //parse jsonRow into a new BaseLookup object and add to rows
            ...
        }

        //add the new records
        dao.callBatchTasks(new Callable<Void>() {
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                for (BaseLookup row : rows) {
                    //this is where I'd like to preserve the existing
                    //value (if any) of the "usageCount" column

                    Dao.CreateOrUpdateStatus result = dao.createOrUpdate(row);
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
```

I've considered attempting to fetch and merge each record individually within the loop, but this seems like it would perform poorly (some tables are a few thousand records). Is there a simpler or more integrated way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think merging the records yourself is your only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to be able to preserve the data in a specific column while creating or updating the records, since I would like to store usage counts (specific to the device) associated with each lookup value

If you have to update certain columns from the JSON data but you want to set the `usageCount` to `usageCount + 1` then you have a couple of options.

- You could build an update statement using the `dao.updateBuilder();`  method and the `UpdateBuilder` class and then update the columns to their new values and `usageCount` to `usageCount + 1` where the id matches.  You should watch the return value to make sure a row was updated.  If none were then you create the object.
- However, it would be easier to just:

  1. get the `BaseLookup` from the database
  2. if null, call `dao.create()` to persist a new entry
  3. otherwise update columns and increment the `usageCount`
  4. and save it back with a `dao.update(...)`

Comment: Thanks, I think the latter solution is probably best for my application since the database size isn't massive. I should look into using UpdateBuilder too, but it seems unnecessary for a relatively simple operation like this.